# modified VLOOKUP in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to modify VLOOKUP function in VBA, but because I work in VBA for the first time a dont know how to do certain things. I want to apply vlookup for e.g. 200 cells in a column at one moment. I found it can be done using for cycle but it didnt work for me. Lets say we have three columns. In first, there are lookupvalues, in second there are some values and in third there shall be lookuped values. Lets say, I want to lookup values only in that rows in which value in second column is zero. And important thing to repeat, I want it by entering formula only in one cell. Can anybody help me? link for image

[image]

Comment: you want a `vlookup` that works like `countifs`? am i correct?

Comment: I cant see anything important what has this function that I want in common with countif. But its possible I just dont understand you.

Comment: `countifs` in excel 2007 and up have multiple criteria. as i understand, you want `vlookup` version with multiple criteria right?

Comment: I added image for better understanding of what I need, I believe it is understandable enought from it.

Comment: How about: `=IF(B1=0,VLOOKUP(A1,I1:J20,2,FALSE),"")`. This only performs the look up where there is a `0` in column B

Comment: As I said, for me it is important that it will be applied on many cells when I type it to only one cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then try this:

```
Function FLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array As Range, col_index_num As Long, _
                  range_lookup As Boolean, Optional ref_value, Optional criteria) As Variant

Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim FirstAddr, find_value As String
Dim my_range As Range
Dim row_count, col_count As Long
Dim check As Boolean

col_count = table_array.Columns.Count
find_value = lookup_value

If col_index_num >= 0 Then
    Set my_range = table_array.Resize(, 1)
Else
    Set my_range = table_array.Resize(, 1).Offset(0, col_count - 1)
End If

With my_range
    row_count = .Cells.Count
    If row_count = 1048576 Then row_count = .Cells(.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Set my_range = my_range.Resize(row_count)
Set LastCell = my_range.Cells(my_range.Cells.Count)

If range_lookup Then
    Set FoundCell = my_range.Find(what:=find_value, after:=LastCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
Else
    Set FoundCell = my_range.Find(what:=find_value, after:=LastCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
End If

If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstAddr = FoundCell.Address
    If IsNumeric(col_index_num) And Abs(col_index_num) <= col_count Then
        Select Case col_index_num
        Case Is > 0
            If IsMissing(ref_value) Then
                FLOOKUP = FoundCell.Offset(0, col_index_num - 1).Value
            Else
                If ref_value = criteria Then
                    FLOOKUP = FoundCell.Offset(0, col_index_num - 1).Value
                Else
                    FLOOKUP = CVErr(xlErrNA)
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Case Is < 0
            If IsMissing(ref_value) Then
                FLOOKUP = FoundCell.Offset(0, col_index_num + 1).Value
            Else
                If ref_value = criteria Then
                    FLOOKUP = FoundCell.Offset(0, col_index_num + 1).Value
                Else
                    FLOOKUP = CVErr(xlErrNA)
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        End Select
        Exit Function
    Else
        FLOOKUP = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
    End If
Else
    FLOOKUP = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Exit Function
End If

End Function
```

Still needs refining but i how this gets you started.

**SYNTAX:**

FLOOKUP (lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, range_lookup, [ref_value], [criteria])

The first four argument is same as `Vlookup` but with `range_lookup` not optional.
The remaining two(2) is optional.
`ref_value` is the value you wish to compare to (in your case values found in Column B).
`criteria` is the test criteria. (in your case 0)

**Here's the screen shot:**
[image: sample image]

Comment: btw, if however your `criteria` are strings, put qoutation marks. Like this `=FLOOKUP(A1,I:J,2,0,B1,"your_string")`.

Comment: It doesnt work for me, I dont know why, I am using same parameters as you are. When I insert some error text, only what happen is that after evaluating there is this error text in cell, where I put formula, other cells are empty. I am still trying to figure out why it does not work for me.

Comment: i updated the code. where did you put the code? should be in a module. after putting it in the module, type the formula seen in the screen shot as is in Column C.

Comment: ah, add this line `Exit Function` after every `FLOOKUP = something`. Sorry I made this in haste :)

Comment: I have put it in module and type your formula, used updated code, addes exit function, but still doest work. When I use it without iferror, I get only #NAME? in that cell

Comment: Could you please upload me your excel file with this function?

Comment: here's the [link](http://wikisend.com/download/427520/FLookup.xlsm). btw, i focused too much on re-creating the `vlookup` well in fact what you want can be accomplished with this formula `=IF(B1=0,INDEX(J$1:J$20,MATCH(A1,I$1:I$20,0),1),"")`. So we really don't need UDF for this. anyways, it's up to you to choose.

Comment: As I said, most important for me is to fill all cells by evaluating formula written in one cell. I will need to do another changes in this UDF, that is reason why formula =IF(B1=0,INDEX(J$1:J$20,MATCH(A1,I$1:I$20,0),1),"") is unusable for me and why I posted this problem here.

Comment: I have little problem with it, because in link, there is flookup.xlst, but when I download it, it is zip file full of xml files and I dont know what to do with it, how to obtain xlst file

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Im using the same. Strange, i checked the link and i download the flookup.xlsm and it works fine. Can someone other than the OP test the file for us?